# MathJax 3 and \overrightarrow

Tags: mathjax

How to fix `\overrightarrow` in MathJax 3?

On Firefox

[image]

and on Chrome

[image]

it looks very ugly (the arrow is not a straight line).

Comment: Does https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2547 help? This looks like a bug of that project, not like anything you can resolve on your own

Comment: Oh, it seems to be a bug then.